# Docker commit : Saving as new image by editing docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I have one docker image which spins up a container for executing some task in a small time period. Container is exited as soon as the task is completed.

Below is the output from `docker ps -a` command

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                         NAMES
40be32cb4299   88841cd3d4a7        "/home/test/testing-…"   40 seconds ago   Exited (0) 22 seconds ago                                                 beautiful_agnesi
```

Since the container is automatically exited in small time period, I can't perform `docker exec -it -u root 40be32cb4299 bash` Output of exec command gives below error since container is exited.

```
Error response from daemon: Container 40be32cb4299 is not running
```

Is there way for me to perform exec on this container for editing some files inside the same container in order to perform `docker commit` and save as new image ?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do it this way, but one of the strengths of Docker is that you script the building of an image in the Dockerfile so you easily can change it and build  a new image. When you manually change a container and commit the changed container to a new image, you lose the record of what was done and it becomes harder to make changes. I would think about if this is the right way to do it or if I could script it in a Dockerfile instead.

Comment: You can run a new container based on the image you already have with an interactive shell; `docker run --rm -it 88841cd3d4a7 sh`.  Based on what you find, to reiterate @HansKilian's comment, _edit your Dockerfile and build a new image_.  `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to exec into a stop container. But, you really have workaround to achieve you aim, something like next:

1. `docker commit 40be32cb4299 old_image`, this commit the old stopped container as an old docker image.
2. `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash --name=new_container old_image`, this use the old image to start a new container. As the `entrypoint` has been override, so the `new_container` will not run your default `entrypoint` or `command`, then `new_container` won't exit, and with `-it`, you are now in the new container.
3. In new container, make file changes.
4. Exit that new container, now you could use `docker commit new_container new_image` to commit your new changes to a new docker image.

Comment: In 4th step while performing docker commit, we can provide --change flag in order to override the initial entrypoint (`--entrypoint=/bin/bash`). So if you want your image to start execution from another entrypoint other that /bin/bash, you can use below command 

`docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["myEntryPoint.sh"]'`

Answer (score 0):

You can start a stopped container. To make this simple name your container

```
docker run --name container_name image_name
```

Start the container using the container name

```
docker start container_name
```

Now exec the rest of the commands

```
docker exec $(docker start container_name) //bin/bash -c " your command"
```

Just remember to run the container without --rm